# Will Apple approve an application that has  PDF and audio files?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am developing an iPhone application that contains audio and PDF files. Will Apple approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think it won't be approved? I have similar apps on the app store, which were approved without any problems.

Comment: may you please guide me what is max file size limit?

Comment: There is nothing like max file size that you can store. I have seen some apps on the app store, storing content(mostly videos) in the order of 1GB. The restriction is only when you transfer data over the air, that too for streaming content. See this: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: There is not max size limit for now, there are some games in appstore which are of 5GB size also

Comment: No I am asking about file (pdf, audio) size limit. if there any.

Comment: No such limits defined till date.